# Copy link to another element

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Wordpress has created a link in '.blog-info' that I want to copy to a blank link (.new-link) further down the page:

```
<div class="blog-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-info"><a href="http://foo.com/deeplink/" title="link title"> Title to story</a><br>
    <div class="blog-date">Leeds, UK, 29th June 2015</div>
    <a class="new-link" href="/">more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are muliple divs that share the same classes and I want each .new-link to copy from its nearest .blog-info a.

Was thinking:

```
$('.new-link').attr('href',$('.blog-info a').closest('a').attr('href'));
```

However this only works for the first link. I need it to contextually copy from the nearest '.blog-info a'. See JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/63zhvj1o/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `each` for iteration. You can use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to set the `href` attribute to the relative `anchor`.

```
$('.new-link').attr('href', function() {
    return $(this).closest('.blog-info').children('a').attr('href');
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/63zhvj1o/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over each anchor element and then set the relevant href from sibling anchor element:

```
 $('a.new-link').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href',$(this).siblings('a').attr('href'))          
 });
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2dcun6r8/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a.new-link').each(function(){
    debugger;
           $(this).attr('href',$(this).siblings('a').attr('href'))          
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-info">
        <a href="http://foo.com/deeplink1/" title="link title"> Title to story</a><br>
        <div class="blog-date">Leeds, UK, 29th June 2015</div>
        <a class="new-link" href="/">more</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="blog-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-info">
        <a href="http://foo.com/deeplink2/" title="link title"> Title to story</a><br>
        <div class="blog-date">Leeds, UK, 29th June 2015</div>
        <a class="new-link" href="/">more</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>   
 <div class="blog-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-info">
        <a href="http://foo.com/deeplink3/" title="link title"> Title to story</a><br>
        <div class="blog-date">Leeds, UK, 29th June 2015</div>
        <a class="new-link" href="/">more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```